# How to define 2 query params with same name in RAML

Tags: rest, raml

I am trying to define RAML for REST API. According to my specification, I need to set 2 query parameters with the same name. There isn't any possibility to change the specification. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation, if you define the parameter as an Array the request can have multiple parameters with the same name. For a more detailed explanation check the [RAML specification on the subject.](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md/#query-strings-and-query-parameters)

For example:

```
types:
  Param:
    type: object
    properties:
      name:
        type: string
  Params:
    type: array
    items: Param
    minItems: 2
    maxItems:2
    uniqueItems: true
```